# Must the refresh_token request come from the same URI origin as in the original redirect_uri?

Tags: oauth, oauth2

I've been playing around with [Oauth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground) to understand Google's Oauth implementation and Oauth in general.

And, I had an idea. I generated an access token running under user_A. Then, I took that access token and used it in Postman to one of the approved scopes API, and it ran fine. Since it worked, I figured I could use it in my Apps Script without doing all the other Oauth plumbing / boilerplate junk. And, it worked fine there too.  What limits stolen access tokens from being totally compromised, though, is that access tokens expire fairly quickly -- usually an hour.  Refresh tokens, on the other hand, are generally indefinite.

There was a question on StackExchange before about refresh tokens being stolen. So, I tried an experiment. I took the refresh token from Oauth playground, and tried using it to refresh the access token on Apps Script, and I got an invalid_grant error.  The HTTP POST request body was created identically to the one in Oauth playground, so I'm thinking there's something else to this.

Reading the Oauth RFC 6749 document on the invalid_grant error, it alludes to the refresh token needing to match the redirection URI used in the authorization request:

```
"invalid_grant
               The provided authorization grant (e.g., authorization
               code, resource owner credentials) or refresh token is
               invalid, expired, revoked, does not match the redirection
               URI used in the authorization request, or was issued to
               another client.
"
```

This makes sense to me, since it would prevent stolen refresh tokens from being used outside the app's domain.  However, I'm not exactly certain, because reading the rest of the standard, I can't find this stated explicitly.  So, does anyone here know?

Comment: There is no redirection involved in the [access token request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749.html#section-4.1.3) nor in the [token refresh request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749.html#section-6). These requests are made from one server to another (and include credentials), and the requested token comes back in the response. Only the [authorization request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749.html#section-4.1.1) in the Authorization Code flow draws a redirection response.